# How to a play Video with in the webviewFrame?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

I am trying to a play video inside the UIWebView frame

I want to play  videos in my webview frame,I saw that there are many options like embedding video and all in UIWebview.But i want it like a player,like youtube player the video will play inside the webview with out showing the fullscreen.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your video hosted on YouTube?

```
let webView = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame) // Position your player frame here

self.view.addSubview(webView)
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(webView)

// Playback options: play in-line and start playing immediately
webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false

// Set the id of the video you want to play
let videoID = "zN-GGeNPQEg" // https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zN-GGeNPQEg

// Set up your player
let embededHTML = "<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}</script><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='\(self.view.frame.size.width)' height='\(self.view.frame.size.height)' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoID)?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1' frameborder='0'></body></html>"

// Load the HTML into your UIWebView
webView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleURL)
```

Alternatively, YouTube provides a great [helper class](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/) for devs to set up YouTube playback in their iOS which sets up the `UIWebView` for you.

Comment: No, my videos are not hosted on youtube,i have my own website in that i am hosting the videos.